# Delete no statistics rasters

Tags: arcpy

I'm trying to write a script that deletes the rasters that have no information at all. Some people told me to use the try/except, using the statistics as a factor to determine if the information exist or not. But when I run the script in my model, it says it's complete, but the image with no information is still there! What am I doing wrong?

This is the script:

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")
for raster in rasters:
    try: 
        arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management (raster, "MINIMUM", "")            
    except:
        arcpy.Delete_management(raster,"")
```

Comment: Your script works fine for me.  Have you tried adding some `print` statements to determine which rasters it is finding, and which rasters it is trying to delete?

Comment: An empty raster can have calculated statistics (so the `GetRasterProperties_management()` won't error out).  Are you sure your raster has no statistics?

Comment: Yes! It has no statistics, an even when i try to use calculate statistics, it doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to delete rasters where all cells are NODATA then this logic would work:

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
    arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")
    for raster in rasters:
        resObj = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(raster, "ALLNODATA") 
        bAllNoData =resObj.getOutput(0)
        if bAllNoData == 1:
            arcpy.Delete_management(raster)
```